# How to display message using WTSSendMessage?

Tags: java, winapi, windows-services, jna

I want to display some message to the user when a task is completed. But the Application is running as a service, so it's not possible to use a UI component.

Microsoft documentation says we can use win32 API: `WTSSendMessage` to show a dialog box. I went through the JNA documentation but couldn't find any reference for this specific thing. I want to do this for a Java application. Is there a way through JNA?

Link to the documentation of WTSSendMessageA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtssendmessagea

Here are some other ways suggested by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I want to display a message box in the client desktop.

Comment: Please link to the MS Documentation you say describes how to do this, or post sample code on how it can be done using WTSSendMessage.  As it currently stands your question is way too broad for anyone to help.

Comment: I have added links now.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the link you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN), a service can

> Display a dialog box in the user's session using the `WTSSendMessage` function.

JNA is comprised of the base functionality in the `jna` artifact and user-contributed mappings in the `jna-platform` artifact.  While the `Wtsapi32` class exists in JNA, only some of that dll's functions have been mapped, but not `WTSSendMessage`.

I note you linked the docs to the -A suffixed version: this is the "ANSI" mapping that does not apply to any modern version of windows.  If you map the un-suffixed version using the WinAPI default type mapper, it will automatically choose the correct -A or -W suffixed version (the difference is that -W uses UTF16 wide strings while -A uses 8-bit ASCII).  But for your convenience you can just map the -W version, [`WTSSendMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtssendmessagew).

Looking down the list of arguments, you need:

- A `HANDLE` obtained from `WTSOpenServer`
- The session to send to (you can use the current session)
- A title bar string you can create
- A message you can create
- A style (you can just use the "OK" version)
- A timeout
- A pointer to receive the response value

For the server handle, the docs for [`WTSOpenServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsopenserverw) state

> You do not need to open a handle for operations performed on the RD Session Host server on which your application is running. Use the constant `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE` instead.

This is already mapped in JNA (it's a `HANDLE` wrapping null).

So you just need to map the `WTSSendMessage` function.  The type mappings are straightforward. `HANDLE` and `LPWSTR` are mapped in JNA, and you should use `int` for the `DWORD` args and `boolean` for `BOOL`.  You'll use an interface, and extend the existing JNA mapping to obtain access to its functions:

```java
public interface MyWtsapi32 extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Wtsapi32 {
    // Your own instance to access your functions
    MyWtsapi32 INSTANCE = Native.load("Wtsapi32", Wtsapi32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    // From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox
    int MB_OK = 0; 

    // The function to send the message
    boolean WTSSendMessageW(HANDLE hServer, int SessionId,
        LPWSTR pTitle, int TitleLength,
        LPWSTR pMessage, int MessageLength,
        int Style, int Timeout, IntByReference pResponse, boolean bWait);
}
```

Then use the functions.  We can use the current server handle, the current session, create our strings to pass, use the "OK" style, and ignore the timeout/response by passing false as the wait parameter.

```java
LPWSTR pTitle = new LPWSTR("Message box title");
int titleLength = ("Message box title".length() + 1) * Native.WCHAR_SIZE;
LPWSTR pMessage = new LPWSTR("Hello World!");
int messageLength = ("Hello World!".length() + 1) * Native.WCHAR_SIZE;
IntByReference pResponse = new IntByReference();

MyWtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTSSendMessageW(
    WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
    pTitle, titleLength,
    pMessage, messageLength,
    MB_OK, 0, pResponse, false);
// should return IDASYNC in pResponse.getValue()
```

This is all untested.  You'll need appropriate imports.

Comment: I have set WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE as NULL and WTS_CURRENT_SESSION as 0, MB_OK as 0. And the code is same but still its not showing any dialog box on run.

Comment: @Mr.code you don't set `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE` to null, you use the constant in JNA's `Wtsapi32` class. It needs to be a `HANDLE` pointing to null.  Also `WTS_CURRENT_SESSION` is a constant in `Wtsapi32` and it has a value of -1.  [See here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/cb31a0ad58484aa0d1935fa92f5cac6abcb1472c/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Wtsapi32.java#L98-L106)

Comment: Dialog box is coming for me when i set WTS_CURRENT_SESSION as 1. Thanks a lot for helping 

Comment: @Mr.code was that 1 or -1?  If it was 1 you got lucky. :)